# How to ensure process window launched by Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo) has focus of all Forms?

Tags: c#

c#.How to ensure process window launched by Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo) has focus of all Forms?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Usage of `SetForegroundWindow` and other methods of setting of focus has a lot of restrictions. If you really want to be sure, that the started process will receive focus I recommend you to use following native (unmanaged) functions

```
SystemParametersInfo (SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT, 0, (PVOID)&dwLockedTimeout, 0);
SystemParametersInfo (SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT, 0, (PVOID)0,
                      SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE | SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

before process start and restore

```
SystemParametersInfo (SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT, 0, (PVOID)&dwLockedTimeout,
                      SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE | SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

at the end. A call like

```
WaitForInputIdle (pi.hProcess, 5000);
```

after the program start and before restoring of `SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT` can be also helpful if you will have problems with immediate

Answer (score 1):

Process.Start returns a Process object. To give the process focus, firstly set up the following PInvoke:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")] static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Then, use:

```
MyProcess = Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo);
SetForegroundWindow(MyProcess.MainWindowHandle);
```