# session0 isolation in Windows 2008/windows7

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, mutex

I have a C++ application which used Mutex, Events,Semaphores for synchronization. While hosted in windows 2008 server/Windows 7, this application is not starting from a remote client.
I used telnet client to connect remotely to this application and saw that telnet server is running under session 0 and therefore it is trying to start my application under session 0.  My application is trying call OpenMutex to open a mutex which was created by another application running locally (in session 1).

I can make my application work by perpending "Global\" to mutex name.  What I am looking for is a way run application without making this code change. Is it even possible? Is it possible to launch telnet service under session 1.

CreateMutex(&sa,FALSE,Buffer, "MyMutexName"));
I can modify this to CreateMutex(&sa,FALSE,SYS_ID2(szSysIdBuffer, "Global\MyMutexName")); but is there any other way other that making this change.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably know the document http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/sysinternals/session0changes.mspx which describes problems with the Session 0 isolation. The old way to make a service interactive which are described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502.aspx not works on Widows 7 because Terminal Services are active per default.

So it seems to me that in your case the way with the "Global\" prefix, which you currently use, is really **the best** one. To understand the complexity of an other possible way you can read following [Process with administrative privileges run on user logon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396134/process-with-administrative-privileges-run-on-user-logon/3397099#3397099).

Comment: Thanks Oleg. Appreciate your confirming the fact that my solution is the "best one".