# Launch process in non-zero session from "user/this account" service

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-services

I have a service (winrshost.exe) which runs as **"User/This account" service**. This service runs in Session "0". This launches "myproc1.exe" as a child process, which also runs in Session 0.

I want to launch another child process (and subsequent child processes) "myproc2.exe" in different non-zero session. Is this possible?

All the google/SO links that talk about this, I believe are for services in "System" account. For e.g. [Launching a process in user’s session from a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128017/launching-a-process-in-user-s-session-from-a-service?rq=4) or this link which many answers have referred: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-32-and-64-bit-Archite

Here is my current code API Flow:

```
GetCurrentProcess()
OpenProcessToken(proc_h, TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_READ | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_EXECUTE | TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hUser)

DuplicateTokenEx(hUser,
            TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT | TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID,
            0, SecurityIdentification, TokenPrimary, &hDupe)
hUser = hDupe;

EnablePrivilege(SE_TCB_NAME, hUser);
EnablePrivilege(SE_IMPERSONATE_NAME, hUser);
EnablePrivilege(SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME, hUser);
EnablePrivilege(SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME, hUser);


SetTokenInformation(hUser, TokenSessionId, &targetSessionID, sizeof(targetSessionID)))

CreateEnvironmentBlock()
ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()
CreateProcessAsUserW()
```

**Call to API SetTokenInformation to change TokenSessionId is successful**.

**Call to API CreateProcessAsUserW fails with error '5' (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)**. I even enabled 'debug permissions' for my user as per article https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/capm?topic=permissions-granting-debug-programs-permission.

If I skip changing TolenSessionId, API CreateProcessAsUserW  is succesful, but the processes are launched in session 0.

Nothing seems to be working so far. Please suggest if this can be achieved at all, or i need to solve this some other way.

P.S. **I have this working when the service runs as 'System' account**, I need to make this work when service runs as 'user/this account' service.

Comment: The process must have the SE_TCB_NAME privilege for set TokenSessionId and you have not it. so what you want ? you noy check result of EnablePrivilege and not need do multiple calls. good code assign multiple privileges in single call.

Comment: @RbMm I have edited my question. The observation about API SetTokenInformation  failing is wrong. With the corrected code, API SetTokenInformation call succeeds. I am calling 'EnablePrivilege' before calling this API.  This calls API 'LookupPrivilegeValue' and 'AdjustTokenPrivileges'. All API calls are succeful. But call to CreateProcessAsUserW fails with error 5. If I skip call to SetTokenInformation , then API CreateProcessAsUserW succeeds, but the session of the child process is 0.

Comment: All API calls are succeful. - no. this is false. you have no SE_TCB_NAME privilege

Comment: Are you saying the process does not have SE_TCB_NAME privilege because it is not a System service? How can I get SE_TCB_NAME privilege for non-System service? The API call are all succesful though, even 'AdjustTokenPrivileges' for SE_TCB_NAME as per my debugging

Comment: yes, you have no SE_TCB_NAME privilege.  The AdjustTokenPrivileges succesful though - this is false, you even can not check this. How can I get SE_TCB_NAME privilege - if your user is admin, you can open some system process token with such privilege. or you can simply take token from existing session and use it

Comment: Thanks @RbMm, can you please help me with some code link/reference for this "if your user is admin, you can open some system process token with such privilege. or you can simply take token from existing session and use it"? I tried opening 'explorer.exe'/'winlogon.exe' process token and it did not help. I am trying to do this in 'myproc1.exe' and NOT in service exe.

Comment: at first - why you suddenly decide start process in another session ? based on which event ? from where you take session id ?  with wjich token you want start process ? normal token from this session ? self token ? system token ? many questions . your first must reply on all it, clear understand what you need todo and for what

Comment: Are you trying running the process with "SYSTEM" access or bypassing UAC escalation?

Comment: I am using winrm4j implementation which relies on 'Windows Remote Management (WS-Management)' service and launches 'winrshost.exe. 'Windows Remote Management (WS-Management)' is running as "Local System", (but should also run as "this user account")

Comment: @user3406792 I guess `EnablePrivilege()` including `LookupPrivilegeValue`.   Does it succeed? After that you should use `WTSQueryUserToken` toObtains the primary access token of the logged-on user specified by the session ID. Succeed? If you provide a minimal reproducible sample will be helpful.

Comment: Thank for the help so far. So here is new update. When I launch "myservice.exe" running as "myuser" account, and launch "myproc1.exe", using the above code, it launches the "myproc1.exe" and subsequent exes in non-zero session. So apparently, we CAN Launch process in non-zero session from "user/this account" service. I am facing issue as I am using 'winrm4j' library to connect to remote desktop which launches "winrshost.exe" service under 'services->svchost->winrshost->myproc1', and it probably has issues? due to which I am facing "-5" error?