# How to make a VB.net 2008 app steal focus on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, vb.net, focus

I'm trying to create an application in `VB.net` that can come to the front once a certain condition occurs (in this case, a file being created). I've tried the following code, but it just results in the taskbar button blinking on `Windows 7`:

```
Me.Activate()
```

I understand the reason for this, and I completely understand why people don't want any random application to steal focus (I hate it too). This is an extremely limited use application (only 3 computers will actually be using it), and the users in this case would want the application to popup in front (there will be an option to turn it off too).

Any ideas if this is still possible to do on `Windows 7`?

Comment: No. There's no (documented) way of disabling the behavior. Otherwise every programmer out there who thinks their application is the best thing in the universe (read: all of them) will abuse it.

Comment: Excellent point :) Is there a setting that I can change on Windows 7? I know on XP you could turn this off.

Comment: As far as I know, no there isn't. Depending on the nature of your application, this might be a good use for [taskbar notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511497.aspx). It's way less intrusive.

Comment: I looked into that, but I really need a way to display an image with it as well.

Comment: Read the first comment again. It's not possible, for the very reason that everyone could think their app is more important than the next one. I'd suggest you stop trying to circumvent the rules and learn to play within them. :)

Comment: This code seems to work: AppActivate("Window Name Here").... but from what all of you are saying, it shouldn't.

Comment: Well, it WAS working, it's not now. Maybe it was working because I was running it directly from Visual Studio? Hmm.

Comment: It works for me by following the Answer of MarkJ. In addition I call AppActivate(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id) as well

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to change the [ForegroundLockTimeout](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957208.aspx) registry key on the three computers. This disables the Windows rules that prevents background applications from stealing the focus. Obviously it will allow *all* applications on the system to steal the focus.

You can also disable the rules through code using [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT` For example see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101061/15639)